# Duplicated results after filtering

Tags: python, django

When I filter by `id`, `first_name` or `last_name` I get duplicated results.
If I put `.distinct()` after `filter()` I get even more duplicate results than before. It seems to be the `involved__user__` relation.

```
order = request.GET.get('order_by','orderDate')
jobs = Job.objects.order_by(order)

            if _filter:
                jobs = jobs.filter(Q(bundle__icontains=_filter) | 
                                Q(onBehalfOf__icontains=_filter) | 
                                Q(involved__user__first_name__icontains=_filter) | 
                                Q(involved__user__last_name__icontains=_filter) | 
                                Q(involved__user__email__icontains=_filter) | 
                                Q(description__icontains=_filter) | 
                                Q(id__iexact=_filter))
```

With `distinct()` I get even more duplicate results than without it:

```
order = request.GET.get('order_by','orderDate')
jobs = Job.objects.order_by(order)

        if _filter:
            jobs = jobs.filter(Q(bundle__icontains=_filter) | 
                            Q(onBehalfOf__icontains=_filter) | 
                            Q(involved__user__first_name__icontains=_filter) | 
                            Q(involved__user__last_name__icontains=_filter) | 
                            Q(involved__user__email__icontains=_filter) | 
                            Q(description__icontains=_filter) | 
                            Q(id__iexact=_filter)).distinct()
```

My model is:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    involved = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, through="Membership")
    ...

class Membership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    ...

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
```

Comment: The duplicates are normal, since you make JOINs here, and thus a `job` can occur multiple times, if there are multiple `involved__user`s for which the condition is satisified.

Comment: But the `.distinct()` should avoid that. Can you show how you use `.distinct()` here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem posted.

Comment: this really looks odd. Does your `order` by any chance contains a related object (like `order_by('involved__user__first_name')`?

Comment: There are furthermore no `.select_related(..)`s?

Comment: what you see is what there is, there is nothing else

Comment: but you order with `.order_by(order)`, and the `order` is not defined here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem here it is. Anyway with or without order_by works.